# How to find minimum temperature using xpath

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, ui-automation

[Website view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtRX0.png)

I want to find the minimum value of temperature using XPath from https://www.timeanddate.com/weather.

I'm using the XPath below but it's not working.

```
//div/span[@class='my-city__wt']/span[@class='my-city__temp'][not(.>//div/span[@class='my-city__wt']/span[@class='my-city__temp']][1]
```

Comment: The minimum value of which temperature? There's a page full of cities and temps on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Selenium** only,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/")
cities = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@class="my-city__item"]')

for city in cities:
    city_title = city.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "my-city__title").text
    city_temp = city.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "my-city__temp").text
    print(f"{city_title}: {city_temp}")
```

and the output:

```
New York: -1 °C
London: 11 °C
Tokyo: 10 °C
```

Using **requests** with **Beautifulsoup**,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = requests.get("https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'lxml')

cities = soup.find_all('div', {"class": "my-city__item"})
for city in cities:
    city_title = city.findNext('a', {"class": "my-city__title"}).text
    city_temp = city.findNext('span', {"class": "my-city__wt"}).findNext('span').text
    print(f"{city_title}: {city_temp}")
```

and we get the city title along with its temperature

```
New York: -1 °C
London: 11 °C
Tokyo: 10 °C
```

**Selenium** with **BeautifulSoup**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

cities = soup.find_all('div', {"class": "my-city__item"})
for city in cities:
    city_title = city.findNext('a', {"class": "my-city__title"}).text
    city_temp = city.findNext('span', {"class": "my-city__wt"}).findNext('span').text
    print(f"{city_title}: {city_temp}")
```

output:

```
New York: -1 °C
London: 11 °C
Tokyo: 10 °C
```